# Two objects have the same exact amount of vertices but blender says they don't?

Tags: rigging, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I am trying to either copy vertices from one object to another or transfer weight.
When I do either, blender says the objects don't have the same amount of vertices and is unable to.

Object 1
[image: Object 1]

Object 2
[image: Object 2]

Copy vertex attempt
[image: Copy vertex attempt]

transfer weight attempt
[image: Weight transfer attempt]

Comment: Hmmm, hard to say without the actual geometry. Can you show that they have the exact same amount of vertices? Maybe upload just those two objects that should be the same to compare them? [Upload file here](https://blend-exchange.com)

Comment: The statistics unfortunately only show the total number of vertices of all visible objects in the scene. To see the number of vertices of a selected object only you need to hide everything except the object (key A and H in object mode)
How have you tried to transfer the weights and vertex groups? It should work when you use the *Data Transfer Modifier*. The modifier doesn't care about the topology and maps the vertices of the source to the nearest destination.